# Is it easy to enter the UK multiple times on the same Business Visitor Visa?

Tags: visas, air-travel, uk, business-travel, repeat-visits

I got a business visitor visa, sponsored by a company, for a 4-5 day visit. The visa was provided for a period of 6 months, with multiple entry possible.

First, what should I carry with me when entering the UK (at LHR)? Will they just take a look at my visa and let me in, or will I have an interview or something? (I haven't seen indication that I should carry documents or anything with me, but I thought I'd ask).

Second, if I want to re-enter the UK in a month or two (not for a business purpose), can I do that on the same visa, since it's multiple entry? Or is the second entry different than the first (i.e. if the first doesn't have an interview, they'll have an interview on the second entry?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The UK Business Visitor Visa is [being abolished in 27 (24 April 2015) days](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/407476/HC_1025_Immigration_Rules.pdf) so your question has limited life.  The new rules will be posted at Immigration Rules [Part 2](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/412242/Immigration_Rules_-_Part_2.pdf)

On the start date (24 April) of the new rules, your BVV will automatically convert to a Visitor (standard) visa. You don't have to do anything for this to happen.

> People who hold a valid visit visa that was issued prior to 24 April
>   2015 can use this to enter the UK provided they are still a genuine
>   visitor.
>
> They will be able to use this visa to carry out the additional
>   permitted activities. For example, a person with a business visit visa
>   can use this to enter the UK for a holiday or to receive private
>   medical treatment.

Source: email from the Home Office to UK lawyers sent on 3 March 2015

The Visitor (standard) visa allows you enjoy tourism or business or recreational coursework for as much as you want on multiple visits until it expires.

For your other questions, you will *always* have a landing interview with a British Immigration Officer who will determine if you still qualify.  They will look at the same paperwork you originally used with your application so you should bring it along.  As long as you are still a genuine visitor, you will have no problems.

Adding

As always, during a transitional period when old rules change to new rules, it's advisable to carry a print-out of the relevant rule with you.

Comment: So, to recap: take documents with me for first business visit, and then after 24 April 2015, it'll basically become a general visit visa which I can use for tourism. Correct?
Also, is there anything in particular one would have to take for a tourism visit (i.e. should I take anything if I take a second trip on this visa post-24-April?). Thanks.

Comment: Always take the stuff you used to get your visa. Tourist or business or whatever.  Always :)

Comment: Right, but if I use the business visitor visa to get into the UK later on after April 24, taking my invitation letter which I used to get the visa and which states the period of 5 days in March in which I have a (business-related) purpose to enter the UK won't help me enter for a tourism-related entry, would it? So what exactly would I take for a re-entry after April 24?

Comment: @Jimmy, you are over thinking this.  Honestly... Always take the stuff you used to get your visa. Tourist or business or whatever. Always :)