# Applying for a UK visa while in the process of separating from my wife

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, business-travel

I am a doctor (neuroanaesthesiologist) working in reputed institute in Delhi and want to attend a conference in UK. I'm married, but have applied for divorce; however this is in the initial stages only. What should I write in marital status? Can I write separated even though I have no legal document to show I am indeed separated. Also I dont want to bring up the fact that a civil case is on, even though it has been filed by me.

Do you think my business academic visitors visa for attending conference in UK will be rejected on this basis? I have the requisite permissions and funding too.

Answer (score 3):

The visitor form has several options for marital status...

[image]

If you are still married, then select the option that indicates you are married. If you have a legal separation, select that one. You should then follow through in Part 4 where it asks "*Does your spouse/partner currently live with you?*"

[image]

...and answer it according to the current status at the time you apply. They don't care about separation unless you and your spouse are legally separated OR unmarried partners and the relationship has permanently broken down and that's not the case with you.

They will not refuse on the grounds that you are having a separation or have filed for divorce.  In cases where a divorce has attracted lurid notoriety in the media, they *STILL* do not refuse on that ground alone.

You can always go to Part 9 and provide a comment, but based upon what you have written, it's not necessary.

You may be over thinking it.  Answer the questions according to what the current status is on your application date.

Related post: [Is it easy to enter the UK multiple times on the same Business Visitor Visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45278/is-it-easy-to-enter-the-uk-multiple-times-on-the-same-business-visitor-visa/45285#45285)