# Is It required to provide Marriage certificate for Separated Spouse applying for student visa?

Tags: visas, uk

I am separated from my husband and I am planning to apply for student visa.

I do not have any legal document yet for the separation.
Is it needed?

Also even in this case is it necessary to provide marriage certificate?

Nationality: Indian. I am applying for visa from India

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Applying for a UK visa while in the process of separating from my wife](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45444/applying-for-a-uk-visa-while-in-the-process-of-separating-from-my-wife)

Comment: Do NOT edit out information of a question. It will only be rolled back. You posted it, you agreed to leave it online. And it may be helpful to others. (But not as edited as you have done now.)

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK a marriage certificate is not a mandatory document for a Tier 4 Study visa application. It is essential to demonstrate that you have:

- an unconditional offer of a place on a course with a licensed Tier 4 sponsor
- enough money to support yourself and pay for your course - the amount will vary depending on your circumstances
- knowledge of English
- tuberculosis test results, if you’re from a country where this is required

The guidance states that you may also need to provide additional documents depending on your circumstances. UKVI may therefore ask for your marriage certificate if they deem it to be relevant and you don’t provide it with the application. If you’re not applying to bring your spouse with you as a dependent, they may not ask for it.

Source: https://www.gov.uk/tier-4-general-visa/documents-you-must-provide