# Return to UK as a tourist on multi entry business standard visitor visa

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, repeat-visits

I hold a multi entry 6 month UK business visa (Standard Visitor Visa) and have already returned from the UK after the business trip.

The visa is still valid and I would like to return as a tourist.

Should I apply for tourist visa again? Or will I be allowed to enter the UK as a tourist.

I know I should ask the embassy but how do I get them to give me a written confirmation?

Comment: Have you tried emailing? UK visitor visas are almost always issued with a 6 month multiple entry validity. However I seem to recall seeing examples on TSE where a visit visa holder was denied entry after completing the trip for which the visa was originally issued, despite it still being valid. Whether this might apply to you would depend on your circumstances eg how long have you already spent in the UK and was this in line with the original application; how soon do you want to return and for how long; do you meet the visa criteria in your own right and can bring documentation to prove it.

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45278/is-it-easy-to-enter-the-uk-multiple-times-on-the-same-business-visitor-visa?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no reason to apply for another visa. Standard visitor visa allows both business visitor and tourist activities. If your visa is no good for another visit there is no point issuing someone a multi entry visa.

Whether you are granted or refused entry is something specific to you and other examples on the internet don’t matter much as long as your intention is to stay within the allowed limits.

Generally for multi entry visas  only the first visit needs to line up with the statements in your visa application. Any subsequent visits don’t need to have the exact same reasons. Don’t even have to call and ask the embassy for it.